# failed to load mod_security module for apache2.2.29 on solaris 10

Tags: apache, mod-security

I just did a fresh install of apache 2.2.29 on my solaris 10 server and then compiled and installed mod_security 2.9 on overtop the same install (this is a 32-bit install) and when I went to load the modules I received an error for the mod_secuirity module.

Here are the modules being loaded in the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule weblogic_module modules/mod_wl_22.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
#LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so

## Mod Security
LoadModule    security2_module        modules/mod_security2.so
```

^^ This last module is the mod_security module throwing a fit.

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 111 of /app/web/test/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /app/web/test/apache/modules/mod_security2.so into server: ld.so.1: httpd: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: symbol gzopen64: referenced symbol not found
```

Does anyone have any ideas to get me going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

run ldd on mod_security2.so, it will probably show it is missing a shared library.
I was unable to get a clean build of mod_security (2.9) w/o adding paths to liblber and libbdb..